# Syntaxerror on downloaded geckofx-18.0-package, how to solve?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, syntax-error, geckofx, generic-type-argument

If I download the source-package of following GeckoFX-Framework 18.0 https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-18.0, open the Geckofx-Core with Visual Studio 2008 and then try to compile it, I got the following error: msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hxfhx4sy(v=vs.90).aspx

I thought it might work at all if I download it from this page. Actually, I don't have that much experiences with C# to figure out which type-definitions I should put in here (I get around 26 Errors with the same type in different locations). Does somebody can help me or get the two dlls of Geckofx-Core and Geckofx-winforms of Geckofx-18.0?

In older Versions it looks like that the developer directly offer those two binaries, too.

Here are the lines with errors:

```
Fehler  3   Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\Net\UploadChannel.cs   21  17  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  4   Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    21  17  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  5   Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoTextNode.cs   24  11  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  7   Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    37  12  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  8   Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\Services\WindowWatcher.cs  39  17  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  9   Die Typargumente der Gecko.nsString.Pass<T>(System.Func<Gecko.nsACString,Gecko.nsACString,T>, string, string)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\Net\DnsService.cs  40  35  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  10  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\Events\DomEventTarget.cs   53  17  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  12  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    57  5   Geckofx-Core
Fehler  15  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    63  5   Geckofx-Core
Fehler  16  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\GeckoWindow.cs 64  17  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  17  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\Events\DomEventTarget.cs   64  17  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  18  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    69  5   Geckofx-Core
Fehler  21  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    75  5   Geckofx-Core
Fehler  25  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    91  5   Geckofx-Core
Fehler  26  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\GeckoWindow.cs 110 17  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  27  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    114 5   Geckofx-Core
Fehler  28  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    138 5   Geckofx-Core
Fehler  29  Die Typargumente der Gecko.nsString.Pass<T>(System.Func<Gecko.nsAUTF8String,T>, string)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.  X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    143 17  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  31  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    176 5   Geckofx-Core
Fehler  32  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    192 33  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  33  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoNode.cs   233 11  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  34  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    239 17  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  35  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    265 17  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  37  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    317 38  Geckofx-Core
Fehler  38  Die Typargumente der Gecko.Interop.ExtensionMethods.Wrap<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>(TGeckoObject, System.Func<TGeckoObject,TWrapper>)-Methode kˆnnen nicht per R¸ckschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.    X:\ixmid\products\geckofx-geckofx-18.0-632b169ff285\Geckofx-Core\DOM\GeckoDomDocument.cs    423 17  Geckofx-Core
```

Comment: If you post the line numbers and lines that are giving you the errors that might help you get an answer.

Comment: I added the errormessages that contains the line numbers. It looks like that Visual Studio 2012 can compile this without those errors as mentioned here: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-18.0/issue/2/when-may-be-download-dll-of-18-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the compiler can't seem to guess the correct types for the generic methods. Newer visual studio compilers seem to be better at this.

I suspect you are using a visual studio older than 2010. Try upgrading to 2010 (Express will do).

Alternatively edit the code to specify the generic types, to help the compiler.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm using VS 2008. Updating to Express is free? Since I'm not familiar with C#-Syntax I preferred the way to wait for an update of the dlls that the developer will offer soon ...)